# How to generate VAST from DoubleClick for Publishers

Tags: double-click, vast

I sign up for DoubleClick for Publishers and created account. My company is video content hosting, and we want to add VAST for the player. We had found examples of VAST/ VPID/ VMAP xml here: https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/flash/tags but I'm not sure how to generate those links form DoubleClick for Publishers interface. Can someone write just simple steps how to do that from there, and I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked out [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/dfp/getting-started/j51SnCLrgqI) thread from Google Help Forum? Actually there are some pretty good advises and directions where to go. Also what you need is called invocation code. You will need to put it in your players's javascript section in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's still relevant (since +2.5 years passed since the question was asked), but as reference, VAST tags can be generated following the steps detailed in this [DFP Help Center article](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1181016?hl=en).